# I am trying to send data from a Cordova app using jQuery serialize and ajax but the data does not seem to be sending

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, cordova-2.0.0

I have already written the code and added all the variables. Can someone point me in the right direction. I have tried placing manual values on the PHP script and it works so I know this is not the problem.

Anyone?

```
$(document).bind('deviceready', function(){
             $(function() {
               $('form').submit(function(){
                                var postData = $(this).serialize();
                                $.ajax({
                                       type: 'POST',
                                       data: postData,
                                       url: '--------------------/submitdata.php',
                                       success: function(data){
                                       console.log(data);
                                       alert('Got it! Thanks for sharing');
                                       },
                                       error: function() {
                                       console.log(data);
                                       alert('Oops, something went wrong. Please try again');
                                       }
                                       });
                                return false;
                                });
               });
             });
```

Comment: do you have more than one forms in your html?

Comment: No @uchamp I only have one form.

Comment: What version of jquery are you on? and when you log the postData var what do you see?

Comment: I am using jquery 1.8.6

Comment: And what do you see when you log the postData variable?

Comment: You can delete the question and your answer.. Its of no use to anyone.. Please keep the site clean..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it. I was reading the wrong variable values from the ajax response which meant that I was actually reading blank data.

Also, my SQL query had  an incorrect parameter. Thank you all for your help :)

Comment: You can delete the question and your answer.. Its of no use to anyone.. Please keep the site clean..